# Mac Read & Write Permissions (w/ plists)

Tags: macos, permissions, plist

So I'm trying to change the plist com.apple.backupd-auto.plist to adjust the timemachine schedule, and when I try to change the number (of seconds, for the schedule), I get the response that I don't have permission. So I just changed the permissions for everybody to "read and write" but then when I go to save, i get the response "cannot save ....plist."

Any ideas?

Thanks -- Kyle

Mac OSX SL 10.6.6 MacBook Pro 6,2

EDIT: using the default mac plist editor

Comment: how are you editing he file?

Comment: oh -- using the default mac plist-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dealing with permissions, I'd go on terminal and

`sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-auto.plist`

Type your password, do your edits and `Control-X` + `y`

Comment: Works as long as the `plist` in question is in XML format. Which this specific one is, fortunately.

Comment: For sure, but in fact it is :)

Comment: this worked great. thx

Answer (score 1):

Many programs *replace* files instead of just changing their contents. *Property List Editor* is one of them.

You need to temporarily give yourself permissions for the parent folder (`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/`) to be able to remove and add files (which is what the program does) and you're good.

Afterwards, change the permissions of the new file to those of the original:

- owned with r/w by `system`
- read-only group `wheel`

---

Alternatively, edit the file in a text editor such as *TextEdit* or one of the "programmers'" text editors such as TextMate. It's easily readable XML, and they don't usually replace the file.